# How do I get a public static IP address in Azure Synapse Analytics?

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-virtual-network, azure-synapse

I need to ingest data from multiple 3rd parties over SFTP in Azure Synapse Analytics. Several of those 3rd parties require requests to come from a single fixed IP address. How can I configure outbound traffic from Synapse to originate from a single IP?

Answer (score 0):

In case if you need a single IP, than the best course would be to set up an IR on a server (since it has a same public IP) and leverage that IR to access SFTP.

Since the Azure IP ranges for an ADF and synapse is not a single IP

Comment: Can you provide more detail or documentation? I did a Google search but didn't come up with much.

Comment: https://sangam-dubey21.medium.com/azure-data-factory-copy-data-from-on-perm-sftp-server-to-azure-blob-93a697a75707
this would provide detail step by step details